# Вывести массив в обратном порядке, а затем удалить из него повторные вхождения каждого элемента

Tags: java

Вот задание: 
 Дан массив целых чисел.
 Вывести массив в обратном порядке, а затем удалить из него повторные вхождения каждого элемента.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] mass2 = new int[8];
    fillMassivRandomNumbers(mass2);
    System.out.println("\n");
    reversOrderMassive(mass2);

}

 public static void fillMassivRandomNumbers(int[] input) {

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 3;
        System.out.print(input[i] + " ; ");
    }
}

public static void reversOrderMassive(int[] input) {


    for (int i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        System.out.print(input[i] + " ; ");
    }
}
```

Результат заполнего массива рэндомно:
    99 ; 101 ; 85 ; 71 ; 12 ; 36 ; 88 ; 53 ;

Перевернул его : 53 ; 88 ; 36 ; 12 ; 71 ; 85 ; 101 ; 99 ;

Но не могу понять :  а затем удалить из него повторные вхождения каждого элемента? 
Если можно помогите обьясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы пришли сюда, чтобы мы за вас решили задание? Спросите о подробностях задания у того, кто вам его дал.

Comment: Да мне не нужно  решение, мне трудно понять , вот и спрашиваю! И сюда пришол за советом не более.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оставить уникальные элементы.

В данном случае, после сортировки можно проверять только следующий элемент и если он равен предыдущему, то его нужно удалить.

**Обновление**

1. Дан массив целых чисел.
2. Вывести массив в обратном порядке.
3. Затем удалить из него повторные вхождения каждого элемента.

**Обновление**

Надо удалить повторные вхождения. Т.е. если массив выглядит следующим образом

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 , 3,
```

должно остаться

```
1,2,3
```

Comment: Чо то я уже запуался( Если я правильно понял вы предлогаете его от сотировать( по убыванию или по возростанию), и если те елементы которые совпаду после перебора удалить а остальные оставить! Получается остаются уникальные, так?

Comment: Первых два пункта уже выполнено. с 3-беда

Comment: Но как вы видете у меня  нет повоторяющихся елементов, как в вашем примере). Имхо нужно задавать массив ручками примерно как вы написали:)

Comment: @Wafe ручками задавать не обязательно. Очевидно, что если повторяющихся элементов в массиве нет, то нужно сообщить об этом пользователю

Comment: Конечно у меня глупая идея, но что если массив записать в Set который сам уберет все повторяющиеся элементы, а потом вернуть все в List ?

Comment: Это нормальная идея, не глупая.

Comment: Только я не подумал о том, что set сам отсортирует весь массив, и поэтому это не подходит.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Всем за разъяснения. Очень приятно что откликнулись и выразили свою точку зрения на задание. 
Решение Задачи для меня понятно, можно несколько вариантов.  

В понедельник отвечу что и как, так как будет занятие! И поставлю галку на решения вопроса:)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользоваться LinkedHashSet

```
 LinkedHashSet<Integer> имя_массива = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(имя_обращенного_массива);
 Iterator<Integer> iter = имя_массива.iterator(); 
    while(iter.hasNext()) { 
        System.out.println(" " + iter.next());
    }
```

Правда вам придется преобразовать ваш массив в List.

Answer (score 1):

По заданию сортировать массив нельзя насколько я понял. Нужно просто его перевернуть, и затем уже пускать двойной цикл. По первому циклу будем брать каждый элемент, во втором бегать по другим элементам и удалять их (то есть все последующие за ним элементы передвигать на `(i-1)`).

Но я бы сделал проще. Есть вот этот перевернутый массив(пункт_2 задания). Создал бы стек, и потом в цикле проверял по массиву, есть такой элемент еще или нет? Если наткнулся на повторный, то

```
stack.push_back(arr[i]);
continue;
```

Главное запоминать уже имеющийся элемент, но это так же можно сделать проверкой - входит элемент в стек или нет.